# Use xib, how to make a height of 0.5

Tags: ios, objective-c

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/u91qmcqg1tdabv4/stackoverflow-01.png

Like this, but, return will make 0.5 change to 0.

Comment: It's possible you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22694062/294884

Answer (score 1):

Call this method(use `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`):

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{    
if (_heightIsZero)
    return CGSizeMake(320, 0);
else
    return CGSizeMake(320, 75);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This height is the calculation of pixels and you cannot put pixels in point; they are always numbers 0,1,2,3,4...